# One Hundred Eyes & Lotus - What fighting style are they using?

Tags: character, marco-polo

In Season 2 Episode 5 of Marco Polo, One Hundred Eyes is training and Lotus enters the room which ends up into a beautiful routine of martial arts. The specific section I'm talking about is on YouTube:

My question is: What style of martial arts is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hundred Eyes](https://www.bustle.com/articles/131537-how-historically-accurate-is-marco-polo-one-hundred-eyes-netflix-is-creating-an-original-special) "fights and trains Marco Polo in the Wu Tang (or [Wudang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wudang_quan)) style" of [Kung Fu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_martial_arts).

Sorry, at first I thought you meant their actual outdoor fight scene because the content of your YouTube link is blocked in the U.S. (*"This video contains content from Weinstein, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds."*) Using a little [VPN magic with Opera](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-in-5-minutes-for-free-and-why-you-urgently-need-one-d5cdba361907) I was able to work around the block and watch the clip. The indoor scene is 1) in Hundred Eyes imagination and 2) not really "fighting". That said, it does look to this "round eye" that they are both using the same boxing and defense style - presumably of Wudang Kung Fu.

Compare the indoor fight to the outdoor fight scene below, starting at 1m10s when they are boxing after the sword fighting. Hundred Eye makes note that Lotus is using Wudang Crane. Possibly in the dream sequence he would not have imagined her using the Crane style?

From what I gather [from fan sites](http://marco-polo.wikia.com/wiki/Hundred_Eyes) for the show, in the outdoor fight Lotus uses [Crane style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujian_White_Crane):

> Hundred Eyes is reunited with a former lover, Lotus, whom he thought was killed during the assault on the Wudang Temple. **In his absence she had trained from his scrolls on the Wudang Crane Style of Kung Fu** and served the Song Dynasty, upon discovery that Hundred Eyes (known formerly as Li Jinbao) has taught their secrets to Monguls and 'round eyes' she gives him a choice; return to the Song Dynasty and fight the Khan or duel to the death.

...this is also evident as some of her moves do in fact resemble the movements of a crane.

Maybe an out-of-universe explanation, but possibly Lotus uses [Crane style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujian_White_Crane) because:

> According to oral tradition, the style was developed by Fang Qīniáng (方七娘; Amoy Min Nan: Hng Chhit-niâ), a female martial artist.

Comment: What do you mean by it's in his imagination? Lotus was well and clearly alive haha. However, you verify my view, something which I could have googled but would rather some insightful views.

Comment: @iZodiac that Lotus is not really there. She disappears at the end. Maybe that is an exquisite Crane technique ;) but I got the feeling that One Hundred Eyes was imagining her because he misses her and thinks she's dead. My reasoning is that in the scene Lotus is not making use of Crane technique because in One Hundred Eyes' imagination, he wouldn't presume her knowledge of Crane technique.

Comment: That does make sense, I have to admit. What about when herself and One Hundred Eyes duel in the forest and looking after Mei Lin's daughter? Was she his imagination then? Or just this scene? She's also left with looking after her daughter too, since Mei Lin and Marco themselves have fought her when she was protecting the Emperor of China

Comment: @iZodiac sounds like a good question to ask the community :)